# How to get the classes of a table header (th) specified in the colgroup

Tags: javascript, dom, html-table, col, class-attributes

With this table,

```
    <table >
    <colgroup>
        <col class="classname1">
        ...
    </colgroup>

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="classname2" scope="col">title</th>
            ...
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
```

I can get the class name specified explicitly on the table header (th) by calling

```
th = document.querySelector...
th.classList // contains classname2 but not classname1
```

Given th, I want to obtain all classnames that apply. How can I get the class names specified in the corresponding colgroup?

Comment: Get the index of the `th` inside the row, and select the `col` element with that same index inside of the `colgroup` ...?

Comment: If the `colgroup` had eg a `span="5"` that might not always work.

Comment: Please give us a better example and tell us what you are trying to achieve (input, expected output). Right now it looks more like an X/Y problem

Comment: @0stone0 sure, and the `th` having one occasionally would give the same problem, in the other direction. So the colspan values would have to be included in the "calculation" of what corresponds to what then. But if that is really necessary here, then OP should provide an example that shows the table is a bit more "complex" to begin with.

Comment: Yep, well completely agree with this probably being an x/y problem. Did get it to work by looping over all the elements and checking `span` to find a matching `<col>`

Comment: @cquezel ... Regarding the so far provided answers / solutions, are there any questions left?

Comment: @PeterSeliger The short answer is no. I was hoping for a simple DOM direct solution given that CSS can use these classes directly to style columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach was to retrieve ...

- within a first step the column specific class-names (as array of class-name arrays) while also taking a col-elements `span`-property into account.
- and within a final step, while iterating the direct child-elements of a specific table-row, to create the array of each child-element's effective class-names array by merging the current element's class-names with the class-names of its related col-element (this time taking into account a child-element's `colSpan`-property).

```js
function getColumnSpecificClassNames(elmTable) {
  return [
    ...elmTable
      .querySelectorAll('colgroup > col')
  ]
  .reduce((result, { span, classList }) => {

    while (span--) {
      result
        .push([...classList]);
    }
    return result;

  }, []);
}
function getRowChildrenEffectiveClassNames(elmTr) {
  const columnClassLists = getColumnSpecificClassNames(
    elmTr.closest('table')
  );
  return [
    ...elmTr.children
  ]
  .reduce(({ result, colCount = 0 }, { colSpan, classList }) => {

    result
      .push([...columnClassLists[colCount], ...classList]);

    return { result, colCount: colCount + colSpan };

  }, { result: [] }).result;
}

console.log(
  'column specifc class names ...',
  getColumnSpecificClassNames(
    document.querySelector('table')
  ),
)
console.log(
  'row children effective class names ...',
  getRowChildrenEffectiveClassNames(
    document.querySelector('table > tbody > tr')
  ),
)
```

```css
.batman {
  background-color: #d7d9f2;
}
.flash {
  background-color: #ffe8d4;
}

caption {
  padding: 8px;
  caption-side: bottom;
}
table {
  width: 49%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 2px solid rgb(100, 100, 100);
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
}
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid rgb(100, 100, 100);
  padding: 10px 10px;
}
td {
  text-align: center;
}
.as-console-wrapper {
    left: auto!important;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>
    <p>Superheros and sidekicks<P>
    <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/colgroup">
      https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/colgroup
    </a>
  </caption>
  <colgroup>
    <col />
    <col span="2" class="batman" />
    <col span="2" class="flash" />
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <th scope="col">Batman</th>
    <th scope="col" class="robin">Robin</th>
    <th scope="col">The Flash</th>
    <th scope="col" class="kid-flash">Kid Flash</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Skill</th>
    <td>Smarts</td>
    <td>Dex, acrobat</td>
    <td>Super speed</td>
    <td>Super speed</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you can search for the index of your targeted `<th>` inside it's parent `<tr>`.
Then loop over each `<col>` and keep track of the (number + `span`). If that exceeds the index found before, you have the correct `<col>`

```js
const th = document.querySelector('.special_th');
const th_row_index = Array.from(th.parentNode.children).indexOf(th)
const all_col = [ ...document.querySelectorAll('colgroup > col') ];

let n = 0;
console.log('Searching for matching <col> that belonges to the <th> on index', th_row_index)
for (let c = 0; c < th_row_index; c++) {
    n += all_col[c].span;
    if (th_row_index <= n) {
        console.log('Found matching <col> with the following class:', all_col[c].className);
        break;
    }  
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.special_th {
  color: purple;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col class="special_col_1" span="2" style="background-color:red">
    <col class="special_col_2" style="background-color:yellow">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th>ISBN</th>
    <th class="special_th">Title</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3476896</td>
    <td>My first HTML</td>
    <td>$53</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5869207</td>
    <td>My first CSS</td>
    <td>$49</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can assign an 'id' to the colgroup you want, then use:

`const colGroup = document.getElementById("yourId")`

`const yourClasses = colGroup.classList`.

It will return an array with all the element classes.